# How can I create a list that counts and displays instances of of duplicates across multiple sheets in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

my goal is ultimately to create a list of bolts in the first sheet that updates itself as I populate other sheets in the same document. The other sheets are for different assemblies for a machine. There are a bunch of different bolts that I have to measure for in cad so it would be nice to have a self populating list as I go through each assembly one by one.

Comment: If you were to share at least an image of what the layout of your spreadsheet is, then it would be a lot easier to formulate an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list of components is in the same column in each of the other sheets (lets say "X" for that column) Then copy column X in each sheet (except the first) into one column in the first sheet and then delete duplicates - the result is a unique list.

```
Sub Assembly()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim y As Integer
Dim t As Range
  For y = 2 To Worksheets.Count
  Set t = Worksheets(1).Range(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'first blankcell in column A
   Application.Intersect(Worksheets(y).Range("X:X"), Worksheets(y).UsedRange).Copy t
Next y
Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1

End Sub
```